# A conjecture about the existence of a member within an interval with certain divisibility conditions - counter examples?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

Conjecture

> The interval of the natural number line $[ap_{n}, (a+1)p_{n}]$ contains a member $e$ that is not divisible by any prime number $p_{m}$ less than or equal to $p_{n}$, if $(a+1) \leq 4p_{n}$,  $a \in \mathbb{N}$

Are there any counter examples?

Comment: Perhaps Bertrand's Postulate (actually a theorem) would be somewhat useful : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a\ge1$ then $[p_n,2p_n]\subseteq[ap_n,(a+1)p_n]$ so it suffices to consider $[p_n,2p_n]$. But $(p_n,2p_n)$ contains a prime by Bertrand's postulate, and such a prime cannot be divisible by $p_n$ or any smaller prime.